# When to clone angular data objects?

Tags: angular, design-patterns, angular-services

Are their any Angular rules/best practices about when to clone or not objects returned by the service.

Sharing same data object reference upon all components may cause unexpected behaviors (eg: template based form that uses object reference may cause object property change before submit)

Answer (score 1):

You should clone your objects when you need to clone them.

A good practice is to have stateless services : they should only perform operations, but have no variables. this means you don't have the same reference everywhere.

You can of course have a statefull service or two, but what I meant was not every single one of them.

Also, when you make http calls, you don't use the same reference to the object you fetched : everytime you make a call, you create a new object.

Is that answering your question ?

Comment: having stateless services may need a huge code change. All my services are statefull. this is because each service need to keep an array of cached data objects for performance issued.

Comment: Well, you asked :P you could cache data in the local/session storage, or gather it in only a couple of services. But if your services are supposed to keep cached data, this means you should not clone your objects ! Since the user don't want to deal with several values for its data, I think you answered your question on your own there

Answer (score 0):

All depends on whether you are ok to submit some data to the server that might possibly be already outdated.

**Example:**

You are about to bid on an item on an auction site, and the last bid was $5. So, you are about to submit $6. However, before you click submit, someone already bid $7.

In the above example, it would be nice to have your bid compared to the last bid on the server & if your bid is lower, the submit button is disabled. **(not cloning)**

Otherwise, your submit hits the auction site and bounces back with an error which your code/form has to handle. A request that you didn't have to send to the server. **(cloning)**

It might be easier to handle the error than constantly update the form. However, the user experience is better when the current bid is updated live.

In short, if you clone the data, your state might get out-of-sync.  With that said, there are use cases for cloning data, for example when the data can't be used as-is and needs further manipulations.